# Can't populate Firebase List Adapter after writing rule

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have been cracking my head to solve this problem and now I have decided to ask the community. I have a list of Locations in my Firebase Database where only selected users can access. Here is a snippet of my Firebase Database:

```
"Locations" : {
   "Location1" : {
     "Users" : "UID1",
     "location" : "Alam Megah",
     "stationNumber" : 1122
   },
   "Location2" : {
     "Users" : "UID1",
     "location" : "Ampang 1",
     "stationNumber" : 1134
   },
   "Location3" : {
     "Users" : "UID2",
     "location" : "Bukit Bintang 1",
     "stationNumber" : 1130
   },
   "Location4" : {
     "Users" : "UID2",
     "location" : "London",
     "stationNumber" : 1130
   },
   "Location5" : {
     "Users" : "UID3",
     "location" : "Paris",
     "stationNumber" : 1130
   },
   "Location6" : {
     "Users" : "UID3",
     "location" : "Singapore",
     "stationNumber" : 1130
   }
 },


 "Users" : {
"UID1" : {
  "UserID" : "User1",
  "Location" : {
    "Location1":true,
    "Location2":true
  },
  "Email" : "user1@abc.com"
},
"UID2" : {
  "UserID" : "User2",
  "Location" : {
    "Location3":true,
    "Location4":true
  },
  "Email" : "user2@abc.com"
},
"UID3" : {
  "UserID" : "User3",
  "Location" : {
    "Location5":true,
    "Location6":true
  },
  "Email" : "user3@abc.com"
}
```

I have written security rules as below so that only selected users can access certain location.

```
{
"rules":{
"Users":{  
     "$uID":{            
        ".read":"auth != null && auth.uid === $uID",
        ".write":"auth !=null && auth.uid === $uID"
     }
   },
   "Locations":{ 
      "$Location":{  
         ".read":"auth != null && (auth.isAdmin==true || root.child('Users').child(data.child('Users').val()).child('UserID').val()==auth.uid)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried running this code in Firebase Simulator in the console under the 'Rules' tab and it works as I want it to. But, when I want to populate this in my listview in Android using the Firebase List Adapter, I can't do it as before because now, I do not have permission to access "Locations" node. And if I grant access to "Locations" node, all childs of "Locations" automatically gain access too. Here are snippets of my Locations, Location List Adapter and LocationActivity classes:

Locations.class:

```
public class Locations {
 private String mLocation;
 private int mStationNumber;
 @Exclude
 private String mUser;

 public Locations() {
}
 public Locations(String location, int stationNumber) {
    mLocation = location;
    mStationNumber = stationNumber;
}
 public String getLocation() {
    return mLocation;
}
 public long getStationNumber() {
    return mStationNumber;
 }
}
```

LocationListAdapter.class

```
public class LocationListAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<Locations> {
 public LocationListAdapter(Activity activity, Class<Locations> modelClass, int modelLayout, Query ref) {
    super(activity, modelClass, modelLayout, ref);
    this.mActivity = activity;
}
@Override
protected void populateView(View v, Locations model, int position) {
    TextView locationName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.locationName);
    TextView locationID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.locationID);

    locationName.setText(model.getLocation());
    locationID.setText(Integer.toString((int) model.getStationNumber()));
 }
}
```

LocationSelectorActivity.class

```
public class LocationSelectorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListView;
private LocationListAdapter mLocationListAdapter;

public LocationSelectorActivity() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    DatabaseReference locationRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Locations");
    mListView = new ListView(this);
    mLocationListAdapter = new LocationListAdapter(this, Locations.class,R.layout.single_location_list,locationRef);

    mListView.setAdapter(mLocationListAdapter);
    setContentView(mListView);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Locations selectedLocation = mLocationListAdapter.getItem(position);

            if(selectedLocation!=null){
                Intent intent = new Intent(LocationSelectorActivity.this, ChecklistSelectorActivity.class);
                String listId = mLocationListAdapter.getRef(position).getKey();
                intent.putExtra("location",listId);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    });

}
}
```

My question is, can I use another method, if available, to iterate through the list of "Locations" and populate using the rules above?

I know from my readings that I cannot use rules as a filter, so what I thought of doing is to have a list of different Location groups, say Location1, Location2 and Location3, each having their own list of users and Locations as children, and consequently create different POJOs and ListAdapters in my Java code, but then, I feel this is redundant as most of the work is done in client side itself. I may be wrong so please correct me if there are other methods.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is there an specific reason  why location doesn't have a .write? ,

Comment: Yes, the users are not allowed to write anything to location. The database will be extended with another node "Checklist" which will allow write operation. This checklist corresponds to the location the user is allowed to access.